# How to filter array with objects based on values in nested array and counting them

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, extract

I have a movies `array` with `objects` listing **genres** (as an `array`) for each movie:

```js
const movies = [
    {
        "title": "Movie A",
        "genre": ["Action", "Sci-Fi", "Thriller"]
    },
    {
        "title": "Movie B",
        "genre": ["Horror, Sci-Fi"]
    },
    {
        "title": "Movie C",
        "genre": ["Action", "Horror", "Thriller"]
    },
    {
        "title": "Movie D",
        "genre": ["Mystery", "Horror", "Sci-Fi"]
    }
];
```

Using (vanilla, ES6+ or Lodash) JavaScript: How do I create a new `array` (see below) with `objects` showing how many times (`count` below) a **genre** (`label` below) is listed in above **movies** `genre` array?

In other words: how many times a genre is listed above.

**End result**: a new `array` sorted alphabeticaly by `label`:

```js
const genres = [
    {
        "label": "Action",
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "label": "Horror",
        "count": 3
    },
    {
        "label": "Mystery",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "label": "Sci-Fi",
        "count": 3
    },
    {
        "label": "Thriller",
        "count": 2
    }
];
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: That is correct and know that. And I changed the question title as requested. I had no idea how to solve this issue or where to begin. Still learning JavaScript. That's why I came to this great place knowing to get an expert answer. Which I did; thank you for that. But somehow this honest question resulted in getting an automatic negative score from the start for 'not trying myself' first.

Comment: Way too many people try to use StackOverflow as a code-writing service for their homework dumps, without making any attempt at all themselves first. That's not what SO is for - rather, SO is meant to be a place for *professional and enthusiast* programmers. Posting a question that doesn't show the slightest amount of effort will (usually) result in downvotes and close-votes - that's just how things are (and should be). (Don't take votes too personally, it's not a judgement on the user, it's a judgement on the post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create the array with the labels and the count

```js
const movies = [
        {
            "title": "Movie A",
            "genre": ["Action", "Sci-Fi", "Thriller"]
        },
        {
            "title": "Movie B",
            "genre": ["Horror", "Sci-Fi"]
        },
        {
            "title": "Movie C",
            "genre": ["Action", "Horror", "Thriller"]
        },
        {
            "title": "Movie D",
            "genre": ["Mystery", "Horror", "Sci-Fi"]
        }
    ];
    var genres = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
        var list = movies[i].genre;
        for (var j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
    
            var existingValue = genres.find(function (value) {
                return value.label === list[j]
            });
    
            if (!existingValue) {
                genres.push(
                    {
                        label: list[j],
                        count: 1
                    }
                );
            } else {
                existingValue.count++;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(genres)
```

Comment: How can I get the grouping of movies by category, i need title of movies

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by putting all the `genre` arrays into an array and then flattening that array using `.flat()`. After that you can then use `.reduce` to create an array of objects from this array.

See working example below (read code comments for further explanation):

```js
const  movies= [{title:"Movie A",genre:["Action","Sci-Fi","Thriller"]},{title:"Movie B",genre:["Horror","Sci-Fi"]},{title:"Movie C",genre:["Action","Horror","Thriller"]},{title:"Movie D",genre:["Mystery","Horror","Sci-Fi"]}];

res = movies.map(({genre}) => genre) // create array of genres (multi-dimensonal)
        .flat() // flatten the array of arrays to only have genres in it
        .sort((a,b) => a.localeCompare(b)) // sort the array alphabetically
        .reduce((acc, genre) => {
          let i = acc.length-1 // get the previous index of the last object
          let prev = acc[i]; // get the previous object
          if(prev && prev.label == genre) { // if the previous label is equal to the curren genre than:
            acc[i].count++; // add one to the current objects count
          } else { // otherwise...
            acc = [...acc, {label: genre, count: 1}]; // append a new object to the accumilator
          }
          return acc; // return the result of the accumilator to be used in next iteration
        }, []); // set starting value of reduce to empty array

console.log(res);
```

Alternatively, if you cannot afford to use the `.flat()` method you can use the following instead:

```js
const  movies= [{title:"Movie A",genre:["Action","Sci-Fi","Thriller"]},{title:"Movie B",genre:["Horror","Sci-Fi"]},{title:"Movie C",genre:["Action","Horror","Thriller"]},{title:"Movie D",genre:["Mystery","Horror","Sci-Fi"]}];

res = [].concat.apply([], movies.map(({genre}) => genre))
        .sort((a,b) => a.localeCompare(b))
        .reduce((acc, genre) => {
          let i = acc.length-1
          let prev = acc[i];
          if(prev && prev.label == genre) {
            acc[i].count++;
          } else {
            acc = [...acc, {label: genre, count: 1}];
          }
          return acc;
        }, []);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

- Get all the `genres` into a string array by using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the string array
- Use `reduce` to get the final object you need

  - Inside this, check if the `counter` object already has a `label` for the current `genre`
  - if yes, increment it, else add a new object to the array

```js
const movies=[{title:"Movie A",genre:["Action","Sci-Fi","Thriller"]},{title:"Movie B",genre:["Horror","Sci-Fi"]},{title:"Movie C",genre:["Action","Horror","Thriller"]},{title:"Movie D",genre:["Mystery","Horror","Sci-Fi"]}];

const final = movies.reduce((genres, {genre}) => genres.concat(genre), [])
  .sort()
  .reduce((counter, genre) => {
    const item = counter.find(c => c.label === genre);
    item ? item["count"]++ : counter.push({ label:genre, count:1 });
    return counter
  }, []);

console.log(final);
```

Or you can create an object with each `genre` as key and the value as the object you need in the final array. Then use `Object.values` to get the desired output:

```js
const movies=[{title:"Movie A",genre:["Action","Sci-Fi","Thriller"]},{title:"Movie B",genre:["Horror","Sci-Fi"]},{title:"Movie C",genre:["Action","Horror","Thriller"]},{title:"Movie D",genre:["Mystery","Horror","Sci-Fi"]}];

const final = movies
              .map(a => a.genre)
              .flat()
              .sort()
              .reduce((a, label) =>
                ((a[label] = a[label] || {label, count: 0})["count"]++,a), {});

console.log(Object.values(final));
```

Comment: How can I get the grouping of movies by category, i need title of movies